# My Shiny App updates data only after I stop and restart the App

Tags: r

The code below is to give the basic idea of my actual code looks like. I have two issues but my main issue is my App's inability to refresh/update tables and selectizeInput options based on a newly added file to a directory. I am new to shiny so don't know much of the lingo but my aim is to upload data to a specific folder and press refresh within the app so that any table and selectizeInput within the App updates to add the new file reactively without me having to stop and re-run my app.

One thing I noticed is that the upload button does send a chosen file to the intended directory. When I refresh, having placed a source function within an observeEvent function in the server section I expect the app to re-run the code that reads and uploads files from my directory to my datatables eventually used by the shiny app, but the table and selectize list don't change and only do so after I close and re-open the app.

Another thing I tried was the history.go(0) solution suggested in many similar questions but that did not work for me. Files still wouldn't update within the app.

My other issue is that I don't know how to save an excel file with custom sheet names. I have had to use numbers now to reference sheets but would have preferred to use sheet names.

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(DT)

source('code.R')


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput('select', 
                 'List of files',
                 multiple = F,
                 choices = c('All', filenames)
      ),
      fileInput('new_file', 
                'Select xlsx File to Upload',
                buttonLabel = 'Browse'
                ),
      hr(),
      actionButton('upload', 
                   'Upload New File',
                   icon = icon('upload')
                   ),
      hr(),
      actionButton('refresh', 
                   'Refresh Page',
                   icon = icon('refresh')
                   )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Selected File',DT::dataTableOutput('data')),
             )
           )
     )
  )

server <- function(input,output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    
    file <- input$new_file
    sheetA <- read_excel(path = file$datapath, sheet = 1)
    sheetB <- read_excel(path = file$datapath, sheet = 2)
    
    write_xlsx(list(sheetA,sheetB), path = glue('Data/{file[1,1]}'))
      
  })
 observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    
   source('code.R')
    
  })
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    
    datatable(combined[combined$file_name == input$select,])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```